# How to check if gridview row has been rendered in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatables

I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) which can filter out specific rows from a table view e.g

```
<tbody>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">...</tr>
  <tr role="row" class="even">...</tr>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">...</tr>
</tbody>
```

When filtered the markup is actually removed.

```
<tbody>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">...</tr>
</tbody>
```

In **VB.NET** I run a loop but the loop still hits every row.

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In gv.Rows

Next
```

### QUESTION

How to skip rows in a for each loop that have not been rendered?

Comment: You are confusing client and server sides. Server has no idea that some rows where removed on the client. You can post some identifiers to the server to describe removed rows

Comment: @Andrei yes but cant I check if the row exists before I post it to the server?

Comment: You can not check it with a gridview. Try to store which rows are displayed before posting a page, maybe with some javascript function after filter event.

Comment: what about checking if the row has a class?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by checking if a .net control within the row had been assigned a value.

If the row was hidden no value was assigned to any controls within that row.